# Disable preventDefault on parent

Tags: javascript

I'm inserting a custom script to tamper with a page. The script adds an input box.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="originalpage">
      <input type="text" id="myinput">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I can't type in the input box becuse the parent element has a script that adds preventDefault() on keypress.

```
function complexKeyHandler(e) {
  // stuff
  e.preventDefault();
}

document.getElementById("originalpage")
  .addEventListener("keypress", complexKeyHandler, true);
```

Using chrome dev tools, I can remove the inherited keypress event on my input textbox without interfering with the original page, and it works properly.

Can I do this from my script? All scripts are vanilla javascript (no jquery).

Comment: `the parent page` - so this is in an iframe?

Comment: No it isn't an iframe

Comment: That's an interesting question... I'm not sure there is much you can do short of removing or modifying the existing event though.

Comment: so how do you have a parent page?

Comment: Misplaced terminology, I meant parent element. Edited

Answer (score 1):

You could remove the `eventListener` like this: `document.getElementById("originalpage").removeEventListener("keypress", complexKeyHandler, true);`

Comment: That would interfere with the function of the page. I don't want remove the original event listener, just prevent it from firing on my custom script.

Comment: remove the listener, add YOUR listener, add the original listener ... I think yours will fire first then